# How to draw line styles network which must look like a line in all directions (Not ribbons)

Tags: c#, xna, directx, shader

I implemented an algorithm to apply some styles (e.g. dash, dotted, dash-dot etc.) on lines. For it, I assumed two points (first and second forming a line) and then fattened each point in its width direction to form a fatten line strip. Thus, I got a fattened line strip and used these lines in making my line strip network to show some data on terrain. Currently, the issue is that when we see a line from sides, it is showing as a Ribbon or Tape, however my boss do not want it. He says,"Line must be looking as a line in all directions.". Although, I can apply bill-boarding on it. But I believe that it will not give a good look to interconnected line networks. Please help me out!

Comment: try asking on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ what type of line you should be aiming for, then ask on SO how you can draw the given line.